# login after page redirect previous post page in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, authentication

I have made login system in WordPress, I want to make a login after page redirect in previous pages in WordPress like I have posts page and have three posts when I log in in third post so after login page will be getting back to third post (same page) in WordPress how can I make a login after redirect on previous page.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has a function that allows you to generate your login URL ([`wp_login_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/)), along with a redirect parameter that will redirect a user to a URL of your choice after they have logged in.

If you use that in conjunction with your current post URL ([`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)) you can generate a login link that will always redirect a user back to post/page they were on when they clicked the link.

When you generate the URL you can use:

```
echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() );
```

For instance, in an `<a>` tag it would look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```